# Find a distribution for this plot

Tags: probability-distributions, regression

Please help me find a formula that fits the distribution. It does not need to be exact, a simple approximation would suffice.

Bonus points if you can tell me which predefined distribution in the python module [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) could be used to generate random numbers from the distribution.

[The plot](https://img.installgentoo.com/di/OB9Q/dist.png) (can't post images because too low rep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) is commonly used. Your plot does look like it might have a sharper peak than that, in which case you might use an [inverse Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) distribution. Both these distributions have two parameters so you'd need to fit them to your data using Maximum Likelihood Estimation. The equations for these are given in the Wikipedia pages.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much what I was looking for.